# "Leaflet" map showing blue background

Tags: r, gis, r-leaflet

I am trying to create a leaflet map in R studio but the map appears to have blue background. Although it is showing the markers but not the actual map.
Initially I thought it is due to slow processing in my system. But I tried on another system as well and got the same result.

Here is my Code,

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet(vert) %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(data = vert, popup = ~location_label(name)) %>%
  addPolylines(data = edges, weight = links$Weight, popup = edge_label(links$Weight)) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) 

m
```

Can anybody please suggest what mistake I am doing. I have all the arguments of the map in place but it still showing blue background.

[image: This is the image of map I am getting.]

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, my mistake. I just realised the problem.
The problem -
The weight of Polylines was ranging from 5 to 1000. Due to this, the entire map was appearing in blue color. When I divided the weight by 50, it started appearing correctly.

Here is the updated code,

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet(vert) %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(data = vert, popup = ~location_label(name)) %>%
  addPolylines(data = edges, weight = links$Weight/50, popup = edge_label(links$Weight)) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) 

m
```

[image: This is the resultant map]